# JUnit obtain systemProperties in IntelliJ but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I try to use a `systemPropertyVariable` defined in the pom over the `maven-surefire-plugin`, when I run a test case from JUnit.

This is the relevant peace of pom.xml file:

```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.16</version>
      <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
          <my.value>NOTNULL</my.value>
          <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This is the test case method:

```
public void testApp(){
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("my.value"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("buildDirectory"));
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("environment.properties"));
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader();
    System.out.println(classloader.getResource("environment" + File.separator + System.getProperty("env")
            + File.separator + "environment.properties"));
}
```

If I run the test case from Eclipse the variables are not available:

```
null
null
null
null
```

But if I run the test case from IntelliJ the variables are available:

```
NOTNULL
/Users/jaimebarrio/git/test-properties/target
null
null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?